# How to return XML from an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I return XML from a controller action? Even when I add the header `Accept: application/xml` it returns a JSON object.

WebApi controllers in MVC 5 supported this. What do I have to do to make it work in MVC 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft removed the XML formatter, so that ASP.NET MVC 6 returns only JSON by default. If you want to add support for XML again, call `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` after `services.AddMvc()` in your `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

To use it, you have to add `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "6.0.0-rc1-final"` as dependency (in the `project.json` under `dependencies`).

---

A slightly more tedious way of doing the same thing would be to add the Xml formatter directly to the OutputFormatters collection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
}
```

`XmlSerializerOutputFormatter` is in the namespace `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters`.

Comment: What class does MvcOptions come from?

Comment: @Nulref It's in the namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: It's now `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml` not `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Xml`

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the current usage, including the namespace change.

Comment: @JimmyBoh thanks, I've edited the question myself, since your edit was rejected.

Comment: @Domysee I actually can't use your way, the extension method doesn't exist anymore (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @JimmyBoh I just tested it today, are you sure you have RC1?

Comment: @Domysee My apologies, I just tried it again and it shows up. Sorry for the confusion, but I'm still not sure why it didn't show up. I was using RC1 Update 1, but now I'm on RC1 Update 2 and it's there.