# How to return xml or json with ASP.NET web mvc 6 depending on Accept Header

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have implemented a web api controller using ASP.NET mvc 6 and I would like to return the result of the controller as json or xml, depending on the client's Accept header. For example, if the client sends a GET request with "Accept: application/xml", then the returned response should be xml. If the header is "Accept: application/json", then it should be json. At the moment the controller always returns json. Is there a way of configuring this? Note: this question is indeed a duplicate of [How to return XML from an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354449/how-to-return-xml-from-an-asp-net-5-mvc-6-controller-action). However the solution provided there did not solve my problem. The accepted answer below worked for me.

The controller is given below and is the one provided by the ASP.NET 5 web api template:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354449/how-to-return-xml-from-an-asp-net-5-mvc-6-controller-action) you may find hints...and this could be a duplicate

Comment: @Prescott yes this might be a duplicate. However I tried to follow the steps provided in your link. This does not seem to work when you are targeting both core and the regular .NET 4.6 framework. I need a solution for both platforms

Comment: I am getting the following error CS0012 The type 'MvcOptions' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. I tried to add "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core" :  "6.0.0-rc1-final" to my project.json but still getting this error. Which package defines MvcOptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did the research for you, you may continue alone:

needed:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

startup:

```
 services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
 {
   options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
 });
```

go on from [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/04/asp-net-mvc-6-formatters-xml-browser-requests/)

[another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619205/asp-net-5-web-api-doesnt-return-xml)

[and antoher](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/24/content-negotiation-in-mvc-5-or-how-can-i-just-write-json.aspx)